# GCC inline assembly error: Cannot take the address of 'this', which is an rvalue expression

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm still fighting with **GCC** - compiling the following inline assembly code (with **-fasm-blocks**, which enables **Intel style** assembly syntax) nets me a strange error **Cannot take the address of 'this', which is an rvalue expression**...

```
MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    _asm
    {
        //...
        mov ebx, this // error: Cannot take the address of 'this', which is an rvalue expression
        //...
        mov eax, this // error: Cannot take the address of 'this', which is an rvalue expression
        //...
    };
}
```

Why can I store pointers to different objects in registers, but can't use pointer to **MyClass** instance?

Comment: Just an afterthought, what about `lea ebx, [this]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the compiler might decide on its own to store `this` in a register (generally `ECX`) instead of a memory cell, for optimization purposes, or because the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall) explicitly specifies it should do that.

In that case, you cannot take its address, because registers are not addressable memory.

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem by creating a local pointer MyClass *p = this and it seems to be working...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A{
public:
    void* work(){
        void* result;
        asm( "mov %%eax, %%eax"
            : "=a" (result) /* put contents of EAX to result*/
            : "a"(this)     /* put this to EAX */
            );
        return result;
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    printf("%x - %x\n", &a, a.work());
}
```

See more details on operands passing to inline asm [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.2)

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure there is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, each implementation defines its own rules with
regards to asm.  In the case of g++, it looks like when you write `mov
ebx, something`, g++ needs the address of `something` in order to
generate the instruction.  (Not to surprising, really, given the way
assemblers work.)  `this` doesn't have an address.  (That's what being
an rvalue means.)  The implementation could treat `this` as a special
case in inline assembler, and replace it with whatever is appropriate at
that spot in the code.  g++ doesn't do this, probably because it has
another, more general mechanism (elder_george's solution) which handles the problem.